# Drupal 7 theme config

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

I am making custom theme for Drupal 7 with features (I mean those items in .info file). So I can use checkboxes to turn them on/off.

Question is that I would like to have a feature to be configured as a string (text input) instead of checkbox.

Do you know how to achieve this?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

These are advanced feature
found on drupal.org: http://drupal.org/node/177868